# Singleton realization for arm-gcc (stm32)

Tags: c++, stm32

I'm testing VisualGDB + CubeMX.
When initialiazing Meyers singleton:

```
class Singleton
{
    
public:
    
    static void update()
    {
        getInstance()._counter++;
    }
    
private:
    
    Singleton() {}
    Singleton(Singleton const &) = delete;
    void operator=(Singleton const &)  = delete;
    
    static Singleton& getInstance()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }
    
    int _counter = 0;
};
```

in a function:

```
extern "C"
void main_loop()
{
    Singleton::update();
}
```

that calls in С code, generated by CubeMX, compiler creates something strange, that eats all memory:

firmware_stm32 section .text will not fit in region `FLASH' firmware_stm32
region FLASH overflowed by 39668 bytes firmware_stm32

Please tell me how I can fix this.

Comment: Please add the compiler command line to your question. Just a guess, you may have to add an attribute to your function to declare where it should be saved in the binary.

Comment: <path_to_compiler>\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe  -g3 -O0 <sources_list> -o firmware_stm32  -"T<path_to_script>/STM32F103C8Tx_FLASH.ld" -Wl,-Map=firmware_stm32.map -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Wl,-gc-sections

Comment: Meyer's singleton pattern is carefully designed to prevent recursive or concurrent initialization. It relies on a similar C++ guarantee regarding initialization of static instances. It comes at price however. It drags in a lot of code from standard C++ library related to locking and threading. This might be the reason the code grows so much. The pattern is mainly targeted at multi-threaded software that wants to achieve quick application starts by lazy late initialization of objects. Do you really need it?

Comment: May be you are right. But I used this pattern in my AVR project, and conpiler genereted compact code in this case

Comment: I think, it is conveniently way. 1. Create singleton class as described above, for example for a led indicator control. 2. Include header file into module, in which it is needed. 3. And just call Led::blink()

Comment: There are more convenient ways like `extern Led powerLed;` in a header file or an *Led* class with all static instance variables and methods. They likely result in smaller code.

Comment: Yes, I guess I'll do it this way

Comment: Disable exceptions && RTTI support.

Comment: I thought it was the default. However, I tried to set these flags explicitly and, unfortunately, I got the same result.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not switch off RTTI yet, because dynamic_cast is still works. How can I do it in VisualGDB project? There's such a confusing project structure!

Comment: do not use visualstudio